# apply xslt to xml content

Tags: xslt

I am using xslt. My input file is

```
    <table bnf_id="bnf_204272" colsep="1" frame="all" id="nzf_3865" otherprops="HRT Risk table"  pgwide="1" rowsep="1"><title>HRT Risk</title><tgroup cols="8" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><colspec colname="col1" /><colspec colname="col2" /><thead><row><entry morerows="1" rowsep="1">Risk</entry><entry morerows="1" rowsep="1">Age range (years)</entry><entry colsep="1" nameend="col4" namest="col3" rowsep="1">Background incidence per 1000 women in Europe not using HRT</entry><entry colsep="1" nameend="col6" namest="col5" rowsep="1"><b>Additional</b>
                  cases per 1000 women using
                  <b>oestrogen only HRT</b>
                  (estimated)
                </entry><entry colsep="1" nameend="col8" namest="col7" rowsep="1"><b>Additional</b>
                  cases per 1000 women using
                  <b>combined (oestrogen-progestogen) HRT</b>
                  (estimated)
                </entry></row><row><entry>Over 5 years</entry><entry nameend="col8" namest="col1"><b>Note</b><p>Where background incidence or additional cases have not been included in the table, this indicates a lack of available data. NS indicates a non-significant difference</p><p>
                    Taken from MHRA/CHM (<i>Drug Safety Update</i>
                    2007;
                    <b>1</b>
                    (2): 2–6) available at
                    <xref format="html" href="http://www.mhra.gov.uk/drugsafetyupdate">
                      www.mhra.gov.uk/drugsafetyupdate
                    </xref></p></entry></row></tbody></tgroup></table>
```

My xslt is

```
 <xsl:template match="tgroup">
<tr>

    <xsl:if test="@cols">
      <xsl:attribute name="cols">
        <xsl:value-of select="@cols"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="@colsep">
      <xsl:attribute name="colsep">
        <xsl:value-of select="@colsep"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@rowsep">
      <xsl:attribute name="rowsep">
        <xsl:value-of select="@rowsep"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@align">
      <xsl:attribute name="align">
        <xsl:value-of select="@align"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="colspec">
      <th>
        <xsl:if test="@colwidth">
          <xsl:attribute name="width">
            <xsl:value-of select="@colwidth"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@colname">
          <xsl:attribute name="colname">
            <xsl:value-of select="@colname"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@align">
          <xsl:attribute name="align">
            <xsl:value-of select="@align"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@colsep">
          <xsl:attribute name="colsep">
            <xsl:value-of select="@colsep"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@colnum">
          <xsl:attribute name="colnum">
            <xsl:value-of select="@colnum"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

      </th>
    </xsl:for-each>


</tr>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

But having the above code in same XSLT file, my second match for th is executed.
So i get the empty th like

```
 <th></th>
```

But i need to insert the `...` between the tags. How to solve it?

Comment: Also, please give you input XML, it is hard to answer your question without it.

Comment: And in addition to the source XML document, please, provide the exact wanted result and explain the rules that the transformation must implement.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i added my input file, i can't place my entire xslt. so i placed the portion of xslt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you simply add the following **xsl:if** condition before the closing </th> tag?

```
   <xsl:if test="@colnum">
       <xsl:attribute name="colnum">
           <xsl:value-of select="@colnum"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:if> 

   <xsl:if test="text() = ''">
      <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
</th>
```